# WebGL - decrease texture intensity

Tags: webgl, textures

I'm using WebGL to create a "3d dog model" , in order to do this I have only to use cubes to build the dog. One of the tasks asks me to apply a texture (that should be a simple checkerboard pattern) that decrease of intensity from the head to the tail of the dog.

This is a view of the dog without the intensity decrease.
[image]

I did not understand how to apply this linear decreasing. Does anyone have any hint ? Thanks

Here is the texture code for the JS file :

```
var texSize = 256;
var numChecks = 8;
var c;

var image1 = new Uint8Array(4*texSize*texSize);

for ( var i = 0; i < texSize; i++ ) {
    for ( var j = 0; j <texSize; j++ ) {
        var patchx = Math.floor(i/(texSize/numChecks));
        var patchy = Math.floor(j/(texSize/numChecks));
        if(patchx%2 ^ patchy%2) c = 255;
        else c = 0;
        //c = 255*(((i & 0x8) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x8)  == 0))
        image1[4*i*texSize+4*j] = c;
        image1[4*i*texSize+4*j+1] = c;
        image1[4*i*texSize+4*j+2] = c;
        image1[4*i*texSize+4*j+3] = 255;
    }
}

var image2 = new Uint8Array(4*texSize*texSize);

// Create a checkerboard pattern
for ( var i = 0; i < texSize; i++ ) {
    for ( var j = 0; j <texSize; j++ ) {
        image2[4*i*texSize+4*j] = 127+127*Math.sin(0.1*i*j);
        image2[4*i*texSize+4*j+1] = 127+127*Math.sin(0.1*i*j);
        image2[4*i*texSize+4*j+2] = 127+127*Math.sin(0.1*i*j);
        image2[4*i*texSize+4*j+3] = 255;
    }
}

var texture1, texture2;
var t1, t2;

var texCoordsArray = [];

var texCoord = [
                vec2(0, 0),
                vec2(0, 1),
                vec2(1, 1),
                vec2(1, 0)
                ];

function configureTexture() {
    texture1 = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture1 );
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, texSize, texSize, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image1);
    gl.generateMipmap( gl.TEXTURE_2D );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                     gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    texture2 = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture2 );
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, texSize, texSize, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image2);
    gl.generateMipmap( gl.TEXTURE_2D );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                     gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 _'gl_FragColor = fColor*(texture2D(Tex0, fTexCoord)*texture2D(Tex1, fTexCoord));'_ this is how I computed the color in the fragment shader , so how do I have to change it ?

Comment: This is what happens with changes I introduced : https://image.ibb.co/fASNBJ/Schermata_2018_05_13_alle_20_45_55.png

Comment: If the mesh doesn't share vertices, you should have a look on vertex colors.